# How to make the shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Could you please help me with the shading? What I need to do is shading the five areas appearing in the uploaded photo and put them all in a frame box. This is my attempt.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    elps/.style 2 args={draw,ellipse,minimum width=#2,minimum height=#1},
    node distance=3cm,
    font=\footnotesize,
    >=latex,
  }
  \node(x)[elps={2.2cm}{1.2cm},label={below left:$dom\ a_{1}\beta a_{2}$}]{};
  \node(y)[elps={2.2cm}{1.2cm},right=of x,label={above right:$im(a_{1})$}]{};
    \node(z)[elps={1.2cm}{2.2cm},below=.-1.2cm of y]{};
      \node(v)[elps={1.2cm}{2.2cm},below right =1.3cm of z,label={below left:$V$}]{};
      \node(w)[elps={2.2cm}{1.2cm}, right=-1cm of v]{};
      \node(r)[elps={2.2cm}{1.2cm}, right=1cm of w]{};
  \draw[->](z)to node[above]{$\beta$}(v);
  \draw[->](x)to[bend left]node[above]{$a_{1}$}(y);
    \draw[->](w)to node[above]{$a_{2}$}(r);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks David! I always get confused with pasting codes correctly

Comment: Presumably `\clip` after `\clip` after ... after `\clip` after `\fill` or `\shade`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partly follow @Symbol's suggestions and also provide a different method in the first example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\image}{im}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    elps/.style 2 args={draw,ellipse,minimum width=#2,minimum height=#1},
    node distance=3cm,
    font=\footnotesize,
    >=latex,
  }
  \node(x)[elps={2.2cm}{1.2cm},label={below right:$\dom a_{1}\beta a_{2}$}]{};
  \fill[blue!30] (x.south) arc[start angle=-90,end angle=0,x radius=0.6cm,y
  radius=1.1cm] -- (x.east) -- (x.center) -- cycle;
  \node(y)[elps={2.2cm}{1.2cm},right=of x,label={above:$\image(a_{1})$}]{};
 \node(z)[elps={1.2cm}{2.2cm},below=.-1.2cm of y,label={right:$\dom \beta q_2\subset \dom\beta$}]{};
  \begin{scope} 
   \clip (z.center) circle[x radius=1.1cm, y radius=0.6cm] ;
   \fill[gray!30] ($(z.south)$) rectangle (z.north -| z.east);
   \clip (y.center) circle[y radius=1.1cm, x radius=0.6cm];
   \fill[blue!30] ($(y.center)+(0,0.2cm)$) rectangle ($(z.south east)+(0,-0.3cm)$);
  \end{scope} 
  \draw[dashed,-latex] (x.-20) to[bend left=10] ($(y.center)!0.5!(y.south)$);
      \node(v)[elps={1.2cm}{2.2cm},below right =1.3cm of z,label={below left:$V$}]{};
      \node(w)[elps={2.2cm}{1.2cm}, right=-1cm of v]{};
  \begin{scope} 
   \clip (v.center) circle[x radius=1.1cm, y radius=0.6cm];
   \clip (w.center) circle[y radius=1.1cm, x radius=0.6cm] ;
   \fill[blue!30] (v.south) rectangle ($(v.north)+(0.7cm,0)$);
  \end{scope} 
      \node(r)[elps={2.2cm}{1.2cm}, right=1cm of w]{};
  \draw[->](z)to node[above]{$\beta$}(v);
  \draw[->](x)to[bend left]node[above]{$a_{1}$}(y);
    \draw[->](w)to node[above]{$a_{2}$}(r);
  \begin{scope} 
   \clip (r.center) circle[y radius=1.1cm, x radius=0.6cm] ;
   \fill[blue!30] ($(r.south)+(0.2cm,0)$) rectangle ($(r.east)+(0,-0.2cm)$);
  \end{scope} 
  \draw (r.south) -- (r.center) -- (r.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marmot. However, there are two shaded areas in the intersections of the second and third ellipses. The one you drew and the one labeled by dom(\beta a_{2}). By the way! do you know how to label these shaded areas? Sorry for annoying

Comment: @MalJA I added the second shading and updated the notation for `dom` and `im`. However, I do not understand what you mean by "label these shaded areas". I added a label to the newly shaded area. Do you want to have arrows like in the photo?

Comment: Many thanks Marmot. what I meant is that there is a shaded area in the first ellipse and I just need to label it with dom (a_{1}\beta a_{2}) not the whole ellipse as I did. Also, there is a dashes arrow connecting the first blue shaded spot with the second blue shaded spot.

Comment: @MalJA I changed the label positions in such a way that it should be clear(er) what they label and added a dashed arrow. If you want to make the labels even clearer, you may add more arrows, but personally I'd not do this because it makes the graph a bit busy.